# Cannot create a standalone browserify module with dollar sign

Tags: node.js, browserify

Trying to Browserify the following module:

```
module.exports = function () {
  return 'test';
};
```

With the `--standalone` option and a standalone module containing a `$` character

```
./node_modules/.bin/browserify src.js --s '$money'  > foo.js
```

Results in a global export of `money` instead of `$money`:

```
f.money=e()
```

`$` is a valid variable/property name, so how can I get browserify to export it as such? This does not seem to be due to shell escaping, but something that browserify/esprima is doing under the hood.

Comment: Where does uglify come into the picture?

Comment: @JMM I'm not sure actually I nuked `node_modules` and the error has gone away. I've edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't actually debug it right now, but it looks to me like it's happening at [ForbesLindesay/umd index.is:57](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/umd/blob/2fc38ac525fce30645ae9832addcc2a6d1360a02/index.js#L57)...

```js
name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, '')
```

...and, like many things about browserify, is undocumented. But in fairness it doesn't appear to be documented by UMD itself.

Comment: That makes complete sense. I guess I'll just manually replace the standalone namespace after browserification. Gotta have those dollar signs :)

Comment: @NickTomlin It looks like this is on the way to be being fixed in browserify. [substack/browser-pack#49](https://github.com/substack/browser-pack/pull/49)